# https express - localhost not working

Tags: node.js, express, https

I'm trying to implement `greenlock-express` in my app. Here is what I did.

```
 var lex = require('greenlock-express').create({
  server: 'staging',
  challengeType: 'http-01',
  challenges: { 'tls-sni-01': require('le-challenge-fs').create({ webrootPath: '/tmp/acme-challenges' }) },
  store: require('le-store-certbot').create({ webrootPath: '/tmp/acme-challenges' }),
  approveDomains: approveDomains
});

var approveDomains = function(opts, certs, cb) {

  if (certs) { 
    opts.domains = certs.altnames; 
  } else {
    opts.domains = ['www.domain.com', 'domain.com']; 
    opts.emails = 'email@domain.com';
    opts.agreeTos = true;  
  }

  cb(null, { options: opts, certs: certs });
} 

require('http').createServer(lex.middleware(require('redirect-https')())).listen(8080, function () {
  console.log("Listening for ACME http-01 challenges on", this.address());
});

// express app settings, router, etc...

require('https').createServer(lex.httpsOptions, lex.middleware(app)).listen(443, function () {
  console.log("Listening for ACME tls-sni-01 challenges and serve app on", this.address());
});
```

So I followed all the steps in the documentation and there are no errors being returned. So I'm doing it right.

The problem happens when I try to access `localhost:8080` it redirects me to `https://localhost` but the page is blank. I don't know why.

I checked if the port is blocked with `nestat -an` and both of their state are set to `listening`.

Not too sure what is going on.

Thank you,
Mark

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Hi @MappaGnosis, we cannot make it work on localhost. Here is the answer that I got: https://git.daplie.com/Daplie/greenlock-express/issues/128